# Cannot reboot Mac into OS X or Windows after installing Windows through Boot Camp

Tags: windows, macos, boot-camp, reboot

I thought I had successfully installed Windows XP on my Mac through Boot Camp when it restarted the computer in order to finalise the installation.

However the problem is that I can't boot neither into OS X nor into Windows.

I've tried restarting the computer and holding down <kbd>Option</kbd> / <kbd>F1</kbd> / <kbd>X</kbd> / <kbd>V</kbd> / <kbd>C</kbd> and I don't get anything except for a blank white screen. The arrow moves around after holding down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key, but no menu appears.

Comment: Do you have your OS X installation disc? Try to boot from it and get into Disk Utility.

Answer (score 1):

As slhck said in his comment, you could use the CD that came with your mac - the OS X install disk, not the application disk. Put it in your CD drive and hold down the 'C' key when you boot up. Then navigate to Disk Utility and see what you can do from there. This is probably your best bet.

You could try something like rEFIt which lets you choose what you boot on startup, but, I think you need access to OS X to install it.

Be very careful while using Disk Utility; don't wipe out your partitions accidentally.